# React-hook-form conditional required validation based on other field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a project with nextjs and typescript in this project I've used react-hook-form for handling my forms. In one of my forms I have a checkbox and if that check box, be checked the Date input should be disabled and unrequired and otherwise the date input should be required.
I saw this solution

[React-hook-form conditional validation of text field, based on if another checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497438/react-hook-form-conditional-validation-of-text-field-based-on-if-another-checkb)

but I use Controller approach and I can't pass function into required this is my inputs

```js
 <div className='flex items-center gap-8'>
                    <InputWrapper
                        hasError={!!errors.expirationDate?.message}
                        errorMessage={errors.expirationDate?.message}
                        required
                        label='تاریخ انقضا'
                        disabled={isFormDisabled || watch('neverExpired')}>
                        <Controller
                            name="expirationDate"
                            control={control}
                            rules={{
                                required: {}
                            }}
                            render={({field}) => (
                                <CustomizedDatePicker
                                    value={field.value}
                                    minDate={new Date()}
                                    name='expirationDate'
                                    onChange={(date: DateObject) => {
                                        field.onChange(date ? date.unix * 1000 : '');
                                    }}
                                    disabled={isFormDisabled || watch('neverExpired')}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </InputWrapper>


                    <InputWrapper
                        labelBesideInput
                        hasError={!!errors.neverExpired}
                        label="هرگز منقضی نشود"
                        id={'neverExpireCheck'}
                        className={'pt-6'}
                        disabled={isFormDisabled}
                    >
                        <Controller
                            name="neverExpired"
                            control={control}
                            render={({field}) => (
                                <Checkbox
                                    inputId={field.name}
                                    onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.checked)}
                                    checked={field.value}
                                    disabled={isFormDisabled}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </InputWrapper>
```

tnx in advance for any effort

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use validation schemas such as [Zod](https://zod.dev/) or [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup), and you can manipulate the schema by the value of `watch('neverExpired')`.